# How do I add a 1-pixel top-margin to the checkbox in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How do I add a 1-pixel top-margin to the checkbox in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="CheckBox">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,1,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It works, and exact the **CheckBox** gets the specified `Margin`. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article about `ElementStyle` property. Also, if you enable editing in your **DataGrid**, you can change the [EditingElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), to apply appropriate lookness of the application.

Comment: Interestingly, when I apply this style to my datagrid with readonly properties, the Checkbox becomes checkable by the user. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="check_box">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Caption" ElementStyle="{StaticResource check_box}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```